# Where to find IBM WebSphere WMQ 6.0 jar files

Tags: jar, ibm-mq

I am trying to implement code where I can send and receive the SOAP messages to IBM MQ. As of my knowledge jar file are required for my code to work, but could not find any place where either I can download the files or can do whole setup of WebSphere 6.0
Do anyone have any idea how can I get it ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? WMQ 6 is out of date for quite a while AFAIK. You may be looking for an WMQ Client of a current version, supposing you have an queuemanager running.

Comment: I am creating a script for putting the message into the queue and receiving it from another queue. Yup we have queue manager running

Comment: The client jars should usually be shipped with the queuemanager distribution.

Comment: @ville the tag [websphere] has nothing to do with this question.   The question already had the proper tag [ibm-mq] so it is sufficient to just remove [ibm].  For reference the [websphere] tag is for questions related to the websphere application server.   Websphere  MQ is a different product which in current versions has dropped the websphere branding and is called simply IBM  MQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be aware that grabbing the jar files from an MQ Server or other installation is *not* supported by IBM and never has been.  However, because it is one of the most commonly used methods to install the MQ client for Java or JMS and fairly common in Java developer culture, IBM has provided a Java-only install option.  Please see the [Redistributable Clients](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q122882_.htm) page in the Knowledge Center for details.

As the name suggests, this install provides an MQ Client package that can be redistributed with independently developed MQ applications.  While that is helpful, the main reason IBM provides it is to provide a lightweight install package that...

1. Contains the correct and complete set of jar files as packaged by IBM.
2. Is intact and verifiable against a known specification and inventory.
3. Can reliably be expected to perform as per the documentation set for that version.
4. Contains all of IBM's diagnostic utilities both in the compiled binaries and in the Java classes.
5. Contains additional utilities such as GSKit for managing certificates.
6. Can be patched using IBM's standard Fix Pack install media so that integrity of the installed classes and libraries is preserved.

When using IBM's install media and procedure, the result is far more stable but int he event something goes wrong, the presence of the diagnostic utilities and conformance to a standard install procedure can dramatically reduce outage durations.

Also, there are occasional instances in which a customer with full support entitlements is told that their non-standard installation is not supported and they need to correct it before continuing the PMR.  Though this doesn't happen often, in most cases the problem is resolved when the MQ client is installed according to spec.  When that doesn't fix it, at least diagnostics can proceed at a faster pace.

The link above has all the details, including links to the client downloads, and is highly recommended reading.  You can also go directly to [Fix Central](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/identifyFixes) for the downloads.  Fix Central offers all supported MQ client versions and the relocatable clients come in v8.0 and up.  In the download list, look for the "All Java" package.

As Tim noted, mixing client and server versions is supported, provided both client and server are currently in service.  Generally you want to develop against the latest version of MQ client because it has the most recent client-side features and will have the longest service life before a version upgrade is required.

Comment: I am trying to go by the method which you are saying. But when I downloaded the 8.0.0.5 version in that I cannot find commonservices.jar which is required. Any idea about how should I proceed further.

Comment: There are two ways to get this officially.  One is the Redistributable Client package, and the other is the MQ Java All package.  Both of these contain `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`.  Drilling down into that jar I find the common services class.  Admittedly, IBM has repackaged the classes but within the jar file all classes know how to access their dependent classes so I have to ask...why do you believe that jar is both required and yet not found?  Is your `CLASSPATH` accessing old jars?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on a Unix platform for your queue manager, the client will be found at:

`/opt/mqm/java/lib`

However, all MQ clients are compatible with all queue manager versions. I strongly recommend you use a client which is still supported, which means 7.1, 7.5, 8.0, or 9.0 at time of writing. These are freely downloadable from the [SupportPac website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007197).

The SupportPacs of interest are those starting 'MQC'. [SupportPac MQC8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24037500&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) for example contains the MQ V8.0 client.

Comment: @Thanks everyone. Just an update to the above answer. In my case I have asked the Websphere administrator for providing me the lib folders which contains all the required MQ jar files. I have asked him to provide following files from "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\"  folders  *   - com.ibm.mq.jar
 *   - connector.jar
 *   - com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
 *   - com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
 *   - com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Just an update to the above answer. In my case I have asked the WebSphere administrator for providing me the lib folders which contains all the required MQ jar files.

I have asked him to provide following files from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\` folders:

```
 * com.ibm.mq.jar  
 * connector.jar  
 * com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar  
 * com.ibm.mq.headers.jar  
 * com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
```

Comment: For the benefit of readers who find this question in the future, grabbing the jar files from the server is *not* recommended despite that you can probably get it to work.  Though this answer may be accepted, it should not be considered authoritative.  I have provided links to IBM's official answer to this question in the form of a Java-only install media and procedure.  Follow that if you need IBM to support the app.  (Also, MQ v6.0 has been out of service since 2009 and is the version where half the Fix Packs were withdrawn due to bugs! Do you *really* want to use THAT?)

Comment: If for some reason you feel you must develop on v6.0 client, you really should go get the documentation while it is still available for download.  See the [WMQ v6.0 Library page](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/library60.html) and look for the downloadable Infocenter packages for Windows and Linux.  Get them soon because almost all traces of MQ v6.0 are gone and these may not be around much longer.